# I would like to generate the reports automatically by accessing data from sql server database. Am using power BI for my report generation

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, powerbi

Am new to power BI and SQL server database stuff. Am working on report generation. MY data lies in different sql servers. I neeed to fetch the data from both the servers and generate the reports in powerBI. I need to generate the dynamic reports. I need some help to make the reports dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Get data to connect and fetch data using SQL query. You have to choose connection type "Direct Query".
One other option for live refresh is using gateway

Answer (score 0):

For Different Servers - you can use different connection using get data connection and then you can connect the data source which you want to connect.

For dynamic generation of report-- there is an option available of refreshing the data of that particular report wither daily or hourly. If you use the pro version then Power BI refresh that particular report hourly but for free version Power bi refresh data on daily basis.

Direct Query-- Using power cloud/service, there is an option available to connect the report directly with Azure, sql server analysis cloud based platform.